# Inequality using lengths of the edges of a triangle

Tags: inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, muirhead-inequality

If $a,b,c $ are the lengths of the edges of a triangle, show that:

$$\frac {6 (a^2+b^2+c^2)}{a+b+c}\geq \frac {(a+b)^2}{b+c}+\frac {(b+c)^2}{a+c}+\frac {(c+a)^2}{a+b} $$

I have no idea how to start.

Comment: I have no idea as well, but from the triangle inequality we have $a  < b+c$ where $a$ is the largest side.

Comment: Identical question here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2874232/prove-that-frac6a2-b2-c2a-b-c-geq-fraca-b2b-c  (currently 2 answers, with no upvotes).